# Badges in tabs reset to 0 if clicked

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

this is my code on my tabs. I dont know what will I do to make the badges count reset to 0 if I clicked on it.  Anyways, I'm using Codeigniter, if anyone knows how to do it. Kindly help me, I will deeply appreciate it. Thank you

```
<div class="container-fluid"  > <!--Main container-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 ui segment" style="min-height:300px;">
            <br>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" style="">Home</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tabbad" href="#menu1">PM's <span class="badge"> 3</span> </a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade panel panel-default  ">
                <div class="panel-body">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Some content.</p>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--Main container-->
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` function in the span

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tabbad" href="#menu1">PM's <span class="badge" onclick="reset(this);"> 3</span> </a></li>
```

Define a reset function/give it any name you like

```
function reset(ttr){
    ttr.innerHTML=0;
}
```

Place the `onclick` function in the `a` element if you would like, and append `"PM"+whatever` value you want.